# Adding a carousel slide handler: works with jquery, fails with d3 select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, coffeescript

So I have a working carousel, super simple. I'm using d3 and noticed an odd difference in how the selections work. I'm trying to figure out why the d3 select fails. I'm happy to use the jquery selector, I just am super curious why this is happening.

For reference:

This works:

`$("#myCarousel").on 'slid.bs.carousel', (e) ->
      console.log('slide event!')`

This fails:

`d3.select("#myCarousel").on 'slid.bs.carousel', (e) ->
      console.log('slide event!')`

BUT this works:

`d3.select("#myCarousel").on 'click', (e) ->
      console.log('slide event!')`

Note that by 'fail' I simply men it doesn't get caught, there isn't an error or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a jQuery plugin for the carousel component. In that case there isn't a way (at least not a standard way) to listen to those events with d3.

`'slid.bs.carousel'` is not an HTML DOM event. It must be some kind of a custom event that the carousel component is written to dispatch. The events are dispatched using jQuery's selection (i.e. the result of `$("...")`) and can be listen to by subscribing to events triggered on that jQuery selection. I.e. jQuery is providing the convenience of making custom events listen-able via the same method interface it provides for listening to DOM events.

D3 doesn't do that. Its `.on()` method, when applied to a DOM selection,  can only receive the DOM events (click, mouseover, etc) that are triggered by those selected nodes.

D3 does provide a way to trigger and listen to custom events, but that listening/dispatching cannot be achieved using d3's DOM selection (ie the result of `d3.select`). Rather, d3 does it by letting you subscribe to an object that's initialized as an event dispatcher using `d3.dispatch()` (see [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#d3_dispatch)). It's equivalent for example to how d3 lets you listen to drag events generated by `d3.drag()` (see reference [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#on)). In that case `d3.drag()` is triggering a `dragstart` event, not the DOM nodes being dragged.